# Alternate position of x tick labels

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to automatically change the position of every other x tick label in pgfplots?

This is my scenario: I have a plot with symbolic x tick labels loaded from the table.  Those labels are too wide to fit next to each other:

[image]

What I would like to have is that every other label is *automatically* shifted a bit downwards like in this example:

[image]

Minimal working code for the "bad" example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
  label     x y
  foobarbaz 0 1
  foobarbaz 1 1
  foobarbaz 2 1
  foobarbaz 3 1
  foobarbaz 4 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      x=1cm,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels from table={data.txt}{label},
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x, y=y] {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the "good" one I manually added `\raisebox` to every other label:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
  label     x y
  foobarbaz 0 1
  \raisebox{-4ex}{foobarbaz} 1 1
  foobarbaz 2 1
  \raisebox{-4ex}{foobarbaz} 3 1
  foobarbaz 4 1
\end{filecontents}
```

However, since my actual data contains much more lines, I don't want to do it manually like this. Is there a way to do this automatically with pgfplots?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use

```
x tick label style={yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
  label     x y
  foobarbaz 0 1
  foobarbaz 1 1
  foobarbaz 2 1
  foobarbaz 3 1
  foobarbaz 4 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      x=1cm,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabels from table={data.txt}{label},
      x tick label style={yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}}
    ]
    \addplot table [x=x, y=y] {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice method! Would you mind also adding an answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164673/positioning-even-or-odd-x-axis-tick-labels-in-pgfplots?