# How to add color and legends to bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, legend

I am trying to create a simple chart using the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={
        Integrated Circuits,
        Transistors,
        Capacitors,
        Resistors,
        Hybrid Circuits,
        Diodes,
        Others,
        Solder Joints
    },
    xtick=data
]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (Integrated Circuits,   27)
        (Transistors,           14)
        (Capacitors,            12)
        (Resistors,             12)
        (Hybrid Circuits,       12)
        (Diodes,                10)
        (Others,                10)
        (Solder Joints,         3)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Since the labels are quite lenghty, it gets displayed like this:

[image]

How can I create a legen on the right hand side of this chart and add Colors to the the bars and legends uniquely.

I had another idea and that is keepin it the same but render the text below the chart vertically

Comment: for the first problem, this post can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296532/alternate-position-of-x-tick-labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may liked sloped x tick labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newlength{\TL}  % Tick Label
 
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\settowidth{\TL}{\footnotesize Integrated}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[    
    width = \linewidth,
    symbolic x coords = {Integrated Circuits, Transistors, Capacitors,
                         Resistors, Hybrid Circuits, Diodes, Others,
                         Solder Joints},
    bar width=11mm,
    ybar,
    xtick=data,
    ticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize,
                       inner ysep=0pt},
    xticklabel style = {text width=\TL, align=right,
                        anchor=north east, rotate=30},
    legend entries={whatever}   % default position is north east
     ]
\addplot coordinates {
                 (Integrated Circuits,   27)
                 (Transistors,           14)
                 (Capacitors,            12)
                 (Resistors,             12)
                 (Hybrid Circuits,       12)
                 (Diodes,                10)
                 (Others,                10)
                 (Solder Joints,         3)
             };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can not appreciate your effort enough. saved my day :)

Comment: @DEKKER, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

- With this post [Alternate position of x tick labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296532/alternate-position-of-x-tick-labels), by increasing the `width` of the graph and with a `\small` font
- for the legend, I deleted in the `addplot` `ybar, fill=blue` and add `ybar` in the `axis environment`

  ```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698728/how-to-add-color-and-legends-to-bar-chart
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
               symbolic x coords={
                       Integrated Circuits,
                       Transistors,
                       Capacitors,
                       Resistors,
                       Hybrid Circuits,
                       Diodes,
                       Others,
                       Solder Joints
                   },
               ybar,%<--- added
               xtick=data,
               width=15cm,
               %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296532/alternate-position-of-x-tick-labels
               x tick label style={
                       font=\small,
                       yshift={-mod(\ticknum,2)*1em}
                   },
               legend entries={I don't know},
               % legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
               %         anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
           ]
           % \addplot [ybar, fill=blue]coordinates {
           \addplot coordinates {
                   (Integrated Circuits,   27)
                   (Transistors,           14)
                   (Capacitors,            12)
                   (Resistors,             12)
                   (Hybrid Circuits,       12)
                   (Diodes,                10)
                   (Others,                10)
                   (Solder Joints,         3)
               };
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]